# regcomp correct syntax

Tags: c, regex

I struggle to find correct way to get my expression work

here is my code

```
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
match(const char *string, char *pattern)
{
    int    status;
    regex_t    re;

    if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED) != 0) {
        printf("@@@@ error\n");
        return(0);      /* Report error. */
    }
    status = regexec(&re, string, (size_t) 0, NULL, 0);
    regfree(&re);
    if (status != 0) {
        printf("@@@@ %d\n", status);
        return(0);      /* Report error. */
    }
    return(1);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ret = match(argv[1], "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*[.]*?");

    if (ret)
        printf("match\n");
    else
        printf("not match\n");

    return 0;
}
```

What I want to achive is to check wether pattern `"user@host132-nd.ts"` in the string `"user@host132.nd/source_dir1"` is present or not.

user can contain only chars, the host can contain chars and digits and also . - _  but the beginning of the string should start with user@host/

I'm not good at regular expressions but I don't want to write a lot of loops and check it all, so the way with regexpr seems more suitable to me.

My expression looks like this:
`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]*[.]*?`

I check it [using some online editors](https://regexr.com/) and its work, at least it find user@host pattern but in my code `regcomp` always failed.

`./a.out user@host123-nd.ts/source_dir1`

`@@@@ error`

`not match`

Thank in advance for any help.

**UPDT:**
I checked error code from `regcomp` and have this error:
`regcomp() failed with 'Invalid range end'`

Comment: Like `regexec` the `regcomp` function returns a non-zero error code on failure, have you checked it?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you I don't know it, I checked it right now `regcomp() failed with 'Invalid range end'`

Comment: Change `[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]` to `[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]`

Comment: @Unimportant thank you its help, now my pattern don't match to what I want to achieve but it's another problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

> The hyphen can be included right after the opening bracket, or right before the closing bracket, or right after the negating caret. Both [-x] and [x-] match an x or a hyphen. [^-x] and [^x-] match any character that is not an x or a hyphen. This works in all flavors discussed in this tutorial. Hyphens at other positions in character classes where they can't form a range may be interpreted as literals or as errors. Regex flavors are quite inconsistent about this.

and you have `...0-9-_`. That second hyphen is what is causing the error. Move it right after opening `[` or right before closing `]`.